# How to embed a gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I wrote a ruby application.

This use a gem, but I don't want to let the user do a `gem install` (because of it need no setup effort). How can I embed a gem in my app?

Comment: You can just move the gem to your application's directory and `require 'path/to/gem'`. If you use a Gemfile, you can supply a path or force a local lookup. Ruby looks for local gems before it looks in the system's gems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try [bundler](http://gembundler.com/)

to package your gem:

```
bundle package
```

to install from cache:

```
bundle install --local
```